# Preparing an input for a shell

Tags: c, parsing

I'm writing a simple shell in C and I want to implement the user input the same way the other shells do, or at least how bash does (never used others).  If you enter a command with random whitespace then it can still run the command:

ex.

> ```
>            ls                              -1
> ```

Obviously `strtok()` wont work on this when separating the command and args...

How does bash do this?  Should I search through the thousands of lines of the source code?

Comment: It may not the way you want to do it but what makes you think strtok wouldn't work?

Comment: @Duck Because I would have to use a space for a delimiter and it produces errors when there are spaces next to each other or right in the beginning

Comment: @Trevor Arjesk, you should probably take a look the source for getopt, getopt_long, etc.

Comment: @Duck: Except those functions take arguments that are already parsed into arrays. So the step that's relevant to the OP (the parsing of the command string into an array) won't be part of their code.

Comment: Ah, true.  Friday nights...time to go to bed.

Comment: I suppose I should read a little more on creating C programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* skip spaces while you're parsing your command:

```
while(*p==' '||*p=='\t') ++p;
```

Comment: yeah thats exactly what i have right now.  is this the most practiced way?

Comment: Actually, what if the arguments contain spaces inside quotes?  A flaw in this method

Comment: I don't see a flaw, you'd only call the space eating method between arguments, the quote string extracting method knows to read spaces.

Comment: I must be missing something...Will I have to write my own method to handle the quotes?

Comment: Yes, parsing a command line is a state machine and space handling is just one state.

Answer (score 0):

whitespaces aren't problem. You can remove all whitespace which is not necesery.
But I'm not sure that shell do it in this way. I think shell may search all option in string which is input. Example

```
ls -a -l    and     ls -l -a
```

is the same. Maybe better will be if you will be search all possible option, or interpret all char step after step. Example, firstly search all "-", after it interpret option which is after "-"

Comment: `ls -a -l` and `ls -l -a` are only the same because `ls` handles them the same. They're certainly not the same to the shell (i.e. in the first case it will set `ARGV` to `{"ls", "-a", "-l"}` and in the second to `{"ls", "-l", "-a"}` - the shell has no knowledge that `ls` doesn't care about the order of the options).